# RemoteViews and Picasso problem with api 24 and above

Tags: android, url, notifications, picasso, remoteview

I use these lines of code for getting notification with image loaded from a url with Picasso library

```
                // Default stuff; making and showing notification
                final Context context = getApplicationContext();
                final NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                final Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon) // Needed for the notification to work/show!!
                        .setContentTitle(eventName)
                        .setContentText(eventTime)
                        .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.logo))
                        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle())
                        .build();
                final int notifId = 1337;
                notificationManager.notify(notifId, notification);
                final RemoteViews bigContentView = 
                notification.bigContentView;
                final int bigIconId = getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/big_picture", null, null);
Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(imageUrl).into(bigContentView,bigIconId, notifId, notification);
                }
```

The code works just fine in api 21 tested it multiple times but on higher APIs like api 24 it gives error says that "RemoteViews must not be null."

here's the error exactly:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.domain.firebaseapp, PID: 31642
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: RemoteViews must not be null.
        at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.into(RequestCreator.java:540)
        at com.domain.firebaseapp.BackgroundService$1.onChildAdded(BackgroundService.java:94)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzbt.zza(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzgx.zzdr(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzhd.run(Unknown Source)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6238)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
```